# Potential Difference and Current dependence

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, potential, electrical-resistance, voltage

When revisiting Ohm's Law, I wondered why (I know it's experimentally derived) the voltage change between two points would depend on current. I could understand this dependence with total energy dissipated in moving a current across a resistor but I can not understand why the P.D. (i.e. the work done *per unit charge*) depends on the current being passed. Essentially, I'm asking why does the amount of energy needed to move a single unit charge depend on how many charge carriers there are with it?

Comment: Do you understand why it takes more force to push a cinder block across a soccer field than to push it across an ice hockey rink?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why, microscopically, is the voltage drop across a resistor affected by the current through it?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/190975/why-microscopically-is-the-voltage-drop-across-a-resistor-affected-by-the-curr)

Comment: @ThePhoton Yes, but that applies to resistive forces like friction, my question would relate more to why the amount/mass of the cinder block affect the pressure (rather than the total force itself as the force would scale up with mass)?

Comment: @Thorondor It answers the sense that the current is dependent on V/R, but I still don't understand then why the amount of energy per unit charge would affect how much charge goes through, why not I = W/R where W is the work done?